# NHibernate - how to call a stored procedure?

Tags: nhibernate

I want to call a stored procedure from My nHibernate application. That stored procedure returns a list and I will return back to the UI. How to call the stored procedure - can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following example.
In you mapping file define the query

```
<sql-query name="MyNameQuery">
        <return-scalar column="SomeColumn" type="String"/>
        <![CDATA[exec proc_MyProc ?]]>
</sql-query>
```

For the call you can do following

```
ISQLQuery objQuery = MySession.GetNamedQuery("MyNameQuery") as ISQLQuery;
                    objQuery.SetParameter(0, "1"); // stored procedure expects a parameter, not used here
                    var myResult = objQuery.List<string>();
```

Comment: i want to call my sp from the application insted of creating a mapping and the domain object for that how do i do that

Comment: this is what i mean 

nhibernate call Stored Procedure to Return a Dataset Without a Mapping Entity

Comment: you can use the Session.Connection property to get the IDbConnection and call the stored procedure from there.